# Ebola - can I enter Indonesia after being an aid worker in Sierrra Leone?

Tags: air-travel, health, indonesia

I will be working in Sierra Leone for 2 months. Then I will either do a 21 day health monitoring quarantine in Canada or France.

If I am negative (no Ebola) after the 21 days, can I fly and enter Indonesia and be considered Ebola free?

Answer (score 5):

Ebola Guidance for Airlines from [Centers for Disease Control and Prevention](http://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/air/managing-sick-travelers/ebola-guidance-airlines.html):

> CDC requests airline crews to ask sick travelers if they were in
>   Guinea, Liberia, or Sierra Leone in the **last 21 days**.
>
> 1. If YES, AND they have any of these Ebola symptoms—fever, severe headache, muscle pain, vomiting, diarrhea, stomach pain, or
>      unexplained bruising or bleeding—report immediately to CDC.
> 2. If NO, follow routine procedures.

So if you stay 21 day in Canada or France there should be no problems. If you stay less than 21 days but don't have any Ebola symptoms it should be ok too.